# Column width in IE7 and Safari 5/OSX too narrow

Tags: css

If you check out the site below in Safari 5/OSX or IE7/Win, the right bottom column  starting with "Stay Updated" (`#secondary`) is super-narrow.

In the CSS it's set to the same width as the "column" directly above it, `#socialsidebar`. Instead of being 31.6667% of the total width of the page I think it might be rendering as 31.6667% of `#socialsidebar`.

http://216.172.167.18/~julia/books/

The width is correct in every other modern browser. Any ideas why this would be happening for Safari 5/OSX and IE7/Win and how to fix it?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing a close-div for the #socialsidebar div. D'OH. Thanks to everyone else who got sucked into my web of stupidity and took the time to look at this. :)

Answer (score 0):

Using the IE developer toolbar and setting a width of 100% to #secondary seems to fix this.  I would recommend setting up a seperate IE7 stylesheet the same way you setup custom classes on your `<html>` tag:

```
<!--[if IE 7 ]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="ie7.css">
<![endif]-->
```

or

```
<!--[if IE 7 ]>
    <script type="text/css>
    enter code here
    </script>
<![endif]-->
```

As to why exactly it's happening, IE7 has some weird display quirks to it.  I rarely dig deep enough to figure out what's exactly going on, as I prefer to spend as little time with it as possible.

A possible resource:  http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html

Comment: Thanks Toast! I actually just figured this out - it was a missing </div>. HEAD-SLAP. So funny how that makes a difference in these two browsers but all the others just rolled with it. Ah well.

Comment: I almost ran it through the w3's validator, too.  Glad you fixed it!

Comment: Yeah, that should have been my first call for sure. :) Dumb assumptions about the cause of an issue like that get me every time.